# Azure IoT Hub messages late/delay/drop

Tags: node.js, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Azure IoT Hub on server side and Azure IoT Client SDK on Device side, we are found 60-65 seconds delay and
drop between device sent a status message over MQTT and message was received by IoT Hub.
In some cases, we are seeing 1-2 minutes delay when IoT Hub enqueued the message.

Below is the code for communication with device to device

```
//'use strict';
//DeviceToCloudMessages libraries
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;
//var base64 = require('base-64');

//*NK+1 19-02-18 CloudToDeviceMessage Libraries
var Registry = require('azure-iothub').Registry;

//CloudToDeviceMessage libraries
var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;


//*NK+1 13-03-18 Get constant values stored in GlobalConstants js
var constant = require('./GlobalConstants');

var connectionString = constant.connectionString;
var serviceClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

//*NK+ 16-03-18 Open service cline
serviceClient.open(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Open connection: ');
    }
});

//*NK+1 19-02-18 Create registry for connection string
var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

//To prevent memory leak
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = Infinity;

//To check device connection state
var request = require('request');
auth = constant.authorization;

//Datetime library
date = require('date-and-time');
var moment = require("moment");

//For log
const fs = require('fs');
var datetime = require('node-datetime');

//For database connection
var sql = require('mssql');
var config =
        {
            user: constant.sUsername, // update me
            password: constant.sPassword, // update me
            server: constant.sServer, // update me
            database: constant.sDatabase,
            options: {
                encrypt: true
            },
             //*start 30-01-18 set resource request timeout 
            connectionTimeout: 0,
            requestTimeout: 0,
            pool: {
                max: 100,
                min: 1,
                idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
            }
            //*end 30-01-18 set resource request timeout 
        }

//*NK+1 23-03-18 declare flag false
//var isLog = false;


// sql.close();
//SQL starts
sql.connect(config).then(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //console.log('sql CONNECTION ERROR');
        console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Opening connection');

    var printError = function (err) {
        logmsg(err.message);
        logmsg('Error from event hub:', err.message);
        startReceiver();
    };

    function logmsg(msg)
    {
        //if(isLog){
            try {
                //console.log(msg);
                var dt = datetime.create();
                var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
                var date = dt.format('Y-m-d');
                var checkhr = dt.format('H');
                var filepath = 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/WebJobLogs/SendD2DMsgLog_' +date +'_' +checkhr + '-00-00'  +'.txt';
                fs.appendFile(filepath, formatted + " " + msg + "\n");
            } catch(error) {
                //console.log(error);
            }
        //}
    }


    function printResultFor(op) {
        try {
            return function printResult(err, res) {
                if (err)
                {
                    logmsg(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
                }
                if (res)
                {
                    logmsg(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
                }
            };
        } catch (exception) {
            logmsg("Print result function " + exception)
        }
    }

    function receiveFeedback(err, receiver) {
        receiver.on('message', function (msg) {
            logmsg('IOT Feedback message:')
            logmsg(msg.getData().toString('utf-8'));
        });
    }

    //*NK+start 19-02-18 for firmware update
    function queryTwinFWUpdateReported(deviceToUpdate) {

      logmsg('deviceToUpdate : ' + deviceToUpdate);
      logmsg('deviceToUpdate : ' + deviceToUpdate);
        registry.getTwin(deviceToUpdate, function(err, twin){
            if (err) {
              //console.error('Could not query twins: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
              logmsg('Could not query twins: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
            } else {
              //console.log('queryTwinFWUpdateReported: ' + (JSON.stringify(twin.properties.reported.iothubDM.firmwareUpdate)) + "\n");
              //logmsg((JSON.stringify(twin.properties.reported.iothubDM.firmwareUpdate)) + "\n");
            }
        });
    }

    function startFirmwareUpdateDevice (linkString, deviceToUpdate) {

        //console.log('linkString: ' + linkString);
        var params = {
          FwPackageUri: linkString
        };

        var methodName1 = "FirmwareUpdate";
        var payloadData =  JSON.stringify(params);
        var payloadData1 = JSON.parse(payloadData);

        logmsg('payloadData : ' + payloadData1);

        var methodParams = {
            methodName: methodName1,
            payload: payloadData1,
            timeoutInSeconds: 3600//,
            //responseTimeoutInSeconds: 3600
        };

        //var methodParamsTest = JSON.stringify(methodParams);
        //var objmethodParams = JSON.parse(methodParamsTest);

        logmsg('methodParams : ' + JSON.stringify(methodParams));
        //console.log('methodParams : ' + JSON.stringify(methodParams));

        serviceClient.invokeDeviceMethod(deviceToUpdate, methodParams, function(err, result) {

            if (err) {
              //console.log('Could not start the firmware update on the device: ' + err.message);
              //console.log('Device: ' + err.stack);
              logmsg('Could not start the firmware update on the device: ' + err.message);
            }else{
              logmsg('success result : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
              //console.log('success result : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
            });
    }
    //*NK+end 19-02-18 for firmware update

    var printMessage = function (message) {
          logmsg('Message received: ');

        try {
            var chunk_msg = JSON.stringify(message.body);
            logmsg(chunk_msg);
            var obj = JSON.parse(chunk_msg);

            //*NK+start 19-02-18 firmware update code
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty('firmwareUpdate')){

                var firmwaretype= obj.controllerName;
                var firmwaremodel= obj.modelNumber;
                var firmwareDeviceId = obj.firmwareUpdate;
                var appDeviceId = obj.appDeviceId;


                new sql.Request()
                                .query("SELECT f.fw_version, f.[loc] FROM <<table>> f WHERE f.[Type] = '" + firmwaretype + "' ").then(function (recordset) {
                            var statusLocation = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                            var obj = JSON.parse(statusLocation);
                            var result = obj.recordset;
                            logmsg('result: ' + result);
                            console.log('result: ' + result);
                            if(result.length > 0){
                                console.log('fw_version: ' + result[0].fw_version);
                                console.log('loc: ' + result[0].loc);
                                console.log('obj.firmwareUpdate : ' + firmwareDeviceId);
                                console.log('obj.appDeviceId : ' + appDeviceId);

                            new sql.Request()
                                .query("select TOP 1 * from <<table>> where Id = '" + firmwareDeviceId + "' order by id desc ").then(function (recordset) {

                                    var status = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                                    var objstatus = JSON.parse(status);
                                    var resultstatus = objstatus.recordset;

                                    var datastatus = resultstatus[0];
                                    var chunkstatus = JSON.stringify(datastatus);
                                    var objnewstatus = JSON.parse(chunkstatus);
                                    var endDate = objnewstatus.last_update;
                                    logmsg('controller last status date ' + endDate);
                                    console.log('controller last status date ' + endDate);

                                    now = new Date();
                                    var currentDate = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                    logmsg('server current date ' + currentDate);
                                    console.log('server current date ' + currentDate);

                                    var start_date = moment(currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                    var end_date = moment(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                    var duration = moment.duration(start_date.diff(end_date));
                                    var hours = duration.asHours();
                                    //var seconds = Math.abs(hours * 3600);
                                    var seconds = Math.abs(hours * 3600);
                                    logmsg('difference in seconds ' + seconds);
                                    console.log('difference in seconds ' + seconds);

                                    if (seconds < 40)
                                    {
                                        logmsg('fw_version: ' + result[0].fw_version);
                                        logmsg('loc: ' + result[0].loc);
                                        console.log('fw_version: ' + result[0].fw_version);
                                        console.log('loc: ' + result[0].loc);

                                        startFirmwareUpdateDevice(result[0].loc, firmwareDeviceId);
                                        setInterval(function() {queryTwinFWUpdateReported(firmwareDeviceId);}, 1000);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        //format failure msg to send to app
                                        var result = '{"response_status":"true","device_id":"' + firmwareDeviceId + '"}';
                                        logmsg('Sending message to app:' + result);
                                        console.log('Sending message to app:' + result);
                                        var message = new Message(result);
                                        serviceClient.send(appDeviceId, message, printResultFor('send'));
                                        logmsg('Feedback Message for firmware upgrade failure sent to app ' + appDeviceId);
                                        console.log('Feedback Message for firmware upgrade failure sent to app ' + appDeviceId);
                                    }
                                }).catch(function (err) {
                                logmsg('firmware upgrade: ' + err);
                            });
                            }


                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            logmsg(err);
                        });
            }
            //*NK+end 19-02-18

            if (obj.hasOwnProperty('command'))
            {
                 logmsg('command exist');
                 console.log('command exist');

                //Send Msg to device
                //serviceClient.open(function (err) {
                    //if (err) {
                    //    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
                    //} else {
                       // logmsg('Service client connected');
                       //*NK+1 23-03-18 Commented feedback receiver
                        //serviceClient.getFeedbackReceiver(receiveFeedback);

                        message.ack = 'full';
                        //message.messageId = "My Message ID";
                        //*NK+1 20-02-18 Update messageId
                        console.log('obj.messageId : ' + obj.messageId);
                        message.messageId = obj.messageId;

                        //Check the status of controller before sending message and return message to user in case of failure
                        var targetDevice = obj.deviceId;
                        new sql.Request()
                                .query("select TOP 1 * from <<table>> where Id = '" + targetDevice + "' order by id desc ").then(function (recordset) {
                            var status = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                            var objstatus = JSON.parse(status);
                            var resultstatus = objstatus.recordset;

                            var datastatus = resultstatus[0];
                            var chunkstatus = JSON.stringify(datastatus);
                            var objnewstatus = JSON.parse(chunkstatus);
                            var endDate = objnewstatus.last_update;
                            logmsg('controller last status date ' + endDate);
                            console.log('controller last status date ' + endDate);

                            now = new Date();
                            var currentDate = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            logmsg('server current date ' + currentDate);
                            console.log('server current date ' + currentDate);

                            var start_date = moment(currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            var end_date = moment(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            var duration = moment.duration(start_date.diff(end_date));
                            var hours = duration.asHours();
                            //var seconds = Math.abs(hours * 3600);
                            var seconds = Math.abs(hours * 3600);
                            logmsg('difference in seconds ' + seconds);
                            console.log('difference in seconds ' + seconds);

                            if (seconds <= 65)
                            {
                                var data = obj.command;
                                //format msg to send to controller
                                var str1 = '{"Name":"Play","Parameters":{"Data":"';
                                var res = str1.concat(data);
                                var str2 = '"}}';
                                var result = res.concat(str2);
                                var message = new Message(result);
                                logmsg('Sending message to controller: ' + message.getData());
                                console.log('Sending message to controller: ' + message.getData());
                                serviceClient.send(targetDevice, message, printResultFor('send'));
                                logmsg('Message sent to controller ' + targetDevice);
                                console.log('Message sent to controller ' + targetDevice);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //*NK+start 29-03-18 Check reset command and send to the server
                                var data_command = obj.command;
                                if(data_command == "<<RESETDEVICECOMMAD>>"){
                                    //format msg to send to controller
                                    var str1 = '{"Name":"Play","Parameters":{"Data":"';
                                    var res = str1.concat(data_command);
                                    var str2 = '"}}';
                                    var result = res.concat(str2);
                                    var message = new Message(result);
                                    logmsg('Reset message is: ' + message.getData());
                                    console.log('Reset message is: ' + message.getData());
                                    serviceClient.send(targetDevice, message, printResultFor('send'));
                                    logmsg('Reset message sent to controller ' + targetDevice);
                                    console.log('Reset message sent to controller ' + targetDevice);
                                }
                                //*NK+start 29-03-18 Check reset command and send to the server

                                if (obj.hasOwnProperty('appDeviceId'))
                                {
                                    //Get app device id
                                    var AppDeviceId = obj.appDeviceId;
                                    //format failure msg to send to app
                                    var result = '{"response_status":"false","device_id":"' + targetDevice + '"}';
                                    logmsg('Sending message to app:' + result);
                                    console.log('Sending message to app:' + result);
                                    var message = new Message(result);
                                    serviceClient.send(AppDeviceId, message, printResultFor('send'));
                                    logmsg('Feedback Message for command failure sent to app ' + AppDeviceId);
                                    console.log('Feedback Message for command failure sent to app ' + AppDeviceId);
                                }

                            }

                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            logmsg(err);
                        });


                //    }
                //});
            }

            else if (obj.hasOwnProperty('u32SH'))
            {
                // console.log('json exist');
                var deviceId = obj.deviceId;
                var data = chunk_msg;
                var datetime = new Date();

                //SQL to get list of device ids
                new sql.Request()
                        .query("select * from <<table>> where id in (select id from <<table>> where id in (select id from <<table>> where Id = '" + deviceId + "')) and connectionState = 'Connected' ").then(function (recordset) {
                    var chunk = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
                    var result = obj.recordset;

                        var message = new Message(chunk_msg);
                        message.ack = 'full';
                        message.messageId = "My Message ID";

                        logmsg('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++)
                        {
                            var data = result[i];
                            var chunk1 = JSON.stringify(data);
                            var obj1 = JSON.parse(chunk1);
                             //Get device id of user
                            var targetDevice = obj1.device_id;

                            serviceClient.send(targetDevice, message, printResultFor('send'));
                            logmsg('Message sent to user ' + targetDevice);

                        } //for loop ends

                }).catch(function (err) {
                    logmsg(err);
                });  //1st sql ends


            } //else if for json object check ends

            //*NK++ 06-03-18 update controller table
            var macId = obj.deviceId;
            updateControllerFirmwareVersion(macId);

        } catch (exception) {
            logmsg("Handling exception....");
            logmsg(exception);
        }

    }; //printMessage function ends

    //*NK+start 05-03-18 update controller firmware version
    function updateControllerFirmwareVersion(deviceId){
        registry.getTwin(deviceId, function(err, twin){
            if (err) {
              //console.log('Could not query twins: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
              console.error('Could not query twins: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
            } else {
              logmsg((JSON.stringify(twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion)) + "\n");
              //console.log((JSON.stringify(twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion)) + "\n");
              //var azureFwVersion = twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion.replace('Azure_Sns_DM V','');
              var azureFwVersion = twin.properties.reported.AzureFwVersion;
              var s = azureFwVersion.lastIndexOf(".");

              var res = azureFwVersion.substring(s+1, azureFwVersion.length);
              //console.log('azureFwVersion: ' + res);
              var firmwareV = Number(res).toString(16).toUpperCase() + '00';
              //console.log('hex : ' + firmwareV);
              logmsg('hex : ' + firmwareV);

                new sql.Request()
                .query("select fw_version from <<table>> where Id = '" + deviceId + "'").then(function (recordset) {
                    logmsg('Get current controller table firmware version');

                    var currentData = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(currentData);
                    var resultstatus = obj.recordset;

                    var datastatus = resultstatus[0];
                    var chunkstatus = JSON.stringify(datastatus);
                    var objnewstatus = JSON.parse(chunkstatus);

                    if(objnewstatus.fw_version != firmwareV){
                        console.log('Available firmware is ' + firmwareV);
                        logmsg('Available firmware is ' + firmwareV);
                        new sql.Request()
                        .query("UPDATE <<table>> SET fw_version = '" + firmwareV + "' where Id = '" + deviceId + "'").then(function (recordset) {
                            logmsg('Updated Controller table for firmware');
                            //console.log('Updated Controller table for firmware');
                            }).catch(function (err) {
                            logmsg('Qry to update Controller table for firmware' + err);
                            //console.log('Qry to update Controller table for firmware' + err);
                        });
                    }

                    }).catch(function (err) {
                    logmsg('Qry to update Controller table for firmware' + err);
                    //console.log('Qry to update Controller table for firmware' + err);
                });

            }
        });
    }
    //*NK+end 05-03-18 update controller firmware version


    var startReceiver = function () {
        try {
            logmsg('Receiver on');
            var client = EventHubClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
            client.open()
                    .then(client.getPartitionIds.bind(client))
                    .then(function (partitionIds) {
                        return partitionIds.map(function (partitionId) {
                            return client.createReceiver('$Default', partitionId, {'startAfterTime': Date.now()}).then(function (receiver) {
                                logmsg('Created partition receiver: ' + partitionId)
                                // receiver.on('errorReceived', printError);
                                // receiver.on('message', printMessage);

                                receiver.on('errorReceived', function callback() {
                                    // console.log('Error Received in receiver');
                                    client.close()
                                    startReceiver()
                                });

                                receiver.on('message', printMessage);

                            });
                        })
                    })
                    // .catch(printError);
                    .catch(function callback() {
                        logmsg('Error Received in catch');
                        client.close()
                        startReceiver()
                    });

        } catch (exception) {
            logmsg("startReceiver function " + exception)

        }

    };

    startReceiver();

}); //sql connection ends
```

Question:
    1. What is the reason for this late/delay/drop in message reaching to IoT Hub?
   2. Is there any issue on node js code?

I am using following node js packages :

```
{
      "name": "Haven",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "AppToServerToDevice.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "azure-event-hubs": "0.0.8",
        "azure-iot-device": "^1.2.1",
        "azure-iot-device-mqtt": "^1.2.2",
        "azure-iothub": "^1.2.3",
        "base-64": "^0.1.0",
        "date-and-time": "^0.6.2",
        "heapdump": "^0.3.9",
        "moment": "^2.20.1",
        "mssql": "^4.1.0",
        "tedious": "^2.1.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {},
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

IOT Hub details :

**IoT Hub details:**
    Pricing tier: S2 standard
    IoT Hub units: 1

SQL database Pricing tier is Standard: S3

Please suggest.

Please see below sample log.

```
2018-04-02 14:00:18 Message received: 
2018-04-02 14:00:23 send status: MessageEnqueued
2018-04-02 14:00:23 send status: MessageEnqueued
2018-04-02 14:00:23 send status: MessageEnqueued
2018-04-02 14:00:23 send status: MessageEnqueued
2018-04-02 14:00:25 {"deviceId":"<<FAKE_ID>>","messageId":54,"u32SH":1094861843,"u32SVN":1215,"u32CVN":645,"u32SRS":2,"u32EVT_ID":9,"u8RSSI":94,"u8C1TID":0,"u8C1ETID":1,"u8C1STId":0,"u8C1ATId":1,"u8C1Rt":3,"u8C1B":36,"u8C1WL":0,"u8C1WB":36,"u8C1SB":68,"u8C1PB":0,"u8C2TID":0,"u8C2ETID":1,"u8C2STId":0,"u8C2ATId":2,"u8C2Rt":11,"u8C2B":99,"u8C2WL":11,"u8C2WB":99,"u8C2SB":99,"u8C2PB":99,"ts":"2018-04-02T14:00:23Z"}
2018-04-02 14:00:25 Message sent to user <<FAKE_ID>>
2018-04-02 14:00:25 Message sent to user <<FAKE_ID>>
2018-04-02 14:00:26 IOT Feedback message:
2018-04-02 14:00:26 [{"originalMessageId":"My Message ID","description":"Success","deviceGenerationId":"636573862820707504","deviceId":"34cebb0dd9eab292","enqueuedTimeUtc":"2018-04-02T14:00:18.6513817Z","statusCode":"Success"},{"originalMessageId":"My Message ID","description":"Success","deviceGenerationId":"636573862820707504","deviceId":"34cebb0dd9eab292","enqueuedTimeUtc":"2018-04-02T14:00:22.9953077Z","statusCode":"Success"}]
```

Comment: This code doesn't really say anything about late/delay message. Is the delay when first received the message from IoT hub (receiver.on('message', printMessage)) or when you've completed the printMessage function? It would be better if you can show logs of when a message is enqueued, dequeued and when the printMessage finishes.

Comment: Thanks Helen for looking the same.
First time or after some time it is working good. But when user pushes command/messages more than 5-7 minutes  then command executed very slow. I found delay almost 60-35 seconds. I have edited it and put the sample log.

Comment: Have you tried your code without SQL connections/query to confirm the issue is with IoTHub? I'm not an expert in Node.js; but there are three types of issues: 1. IoT Hub, 2. Node.js code 3.SQL logic with code. I think it's best break up your code to see where the issue might be?

Comment: @HelenLo I tried the same things before put the question on here. The major issue is, node.js code pushes the commands/messages to IoT Hub. (I seen the logs on console.) But eventually it executed after 10-20 sec. (Sometime user wait more than 30 sec to execute the command/messages). I can't debug my commands/messages reaches the IT Hub endpoint or not. Do you have any idea to test the commands/messages reached o IoT hub endpoint?

Comment: I send D2C messages using [simple_sample_device.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/device/samples) sample and receive these message in [device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer), testing keep running for more than 10 minutes and the time difference between two message is <= 2 seconds. You can try and to see if it can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks @RitaHan-MSFT I changed the code, and got some improvement. But not though enough.

Comment: Have you tested the sample code with no changes?

Comment: Actually I had remove all the sql queries/connection and change the code as per sample code provided by you. So I got some improvement, but not satisfactory.
Do you have any idea to catch/debug IoT Hub endpoint messages/commands? So I will know where exact I will look into the code.